Sitecore SXA Redirect Map Local CMS
I am using Sitecore 10.3.1 with JSS-Next.js app (version 21.5.3) and Node (version 21.7.3).
I am using the redirect map feature in SXA, where I have specified the source and destination URLs as shown in the screenshot. The issue is that, when I access the test page, it should redirect to the "About Us" page.
While the redirection works properly in the development environment, it doesn't working on my local setup.
Local URL: http://localhost:3000/test

please provide the solution.

We're going to need more information. What have you tried? What if anything is in the logs? Have you looked at the site redirect query in graphql to see if that is returning the expected content?

Does the test item exist in the content tree?

Can you try to set the disabled parameter to false in redirect.ts file and check. By default for development node(local instance) it will be disabled.

@DeanOBrien - /test page does not exists in the content tree.

In the redirect.ts file change the disabled parameter to false to make the redirects work in the local environment.
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { RedirectsMiddleware } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs/middleware';
import { MiddlewarePlugin } from '..';
import { siteResolver } from 'lib/site-resolver';
import clientFactory from 'lib/graphql-client-factory';

class RedirectsPlugin implements MiddlewarePlugin {
  private redirectsMiddleware: RedirectsMiddleware;
  order = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.redirectsMiddleware = new RedirectsMiddleware({
      // Client factory implementation
      clientFactory,
      // These are all the locales you support in your application.
      // These should match those in your next.config.js (i18n.locales).
      locales: ['en'],
      // This function determines if a route should be excluded from RedirectsMiddleware.
      // Certain paths are ignored by default (e.g. Next.js API routes), but you may wish to exclude more.
      // This is an important performance consideration since Next.js Edge middleware runs on every request.
      excludeRoute: () => false,
      // This function determines if the middleware should be turned off.
      // By default it is disabled while in development mode.
      disabled: () => false,
      // Site resolver implementation
      siteResolver,
    });
  }

  /**
   * exec async method - to find coincidence in url.pathname and redirects of site
   * @param req<NextRequest>
   * @returns Promise<NextResponse>
   */
  async exec(req: NextRequest, res?: NextResponse): Promise<NextResponse> {
    return this.redirectsMiddleware.getHandler()(req, res);
  }
}

export const redirectsPlugin = new RedirectsPlugin();


Thank you for the answer. yes, my local redirection is working but when i change the new destination URL. it's always redirecting into old destination URL not new destination URL. even i tried with restarted the server.
Old destination URL
/test to /about-us
New destination URL
/test to /our-leadership

Can you check the endpoint. Is it local or Edge. It should be auto updated. If you are using GraphQL and Edge, check the redirects with this query:
query {
site{
siteInfo(site:"your-site"){
redirects{
pattern
target
}
}
}
}
